# Momentum conservation in photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

In analyzing Compton scattering we consider the conservation of both energy and momentum.

However, in analyzing the photoelectric effect only the conservation of energy is taken into account.

In fact, if the momentum of the photon is taken into account there seems to be a violation of the law of conservation of momentum. The momentum of the photon is into the metal but the momentum of the ejected electron is out of the metal i.e. the momentum of the ejected electron has a component opposite to the momentum of the incident photon.

A way out would be to argue that the process of ejection is complicated and that it is actually the atom which ejects the electron. There is, however, a problem here. Experiments with linearly polarized x-rays or ultraviolet light show that the electron is always ejected in a direction parallel to the electric vector i.e. perpendicular to the direction of the incident beam of photons. This suggests that it is indeed the photon which ejects the electron, not the atom.

Is there an explanation in either quantum mechanics or classical electromagnetism or both?

Comment: The rest of the metal makes sure that momentum is conserved.

Comment: That would be like a ball bouncing off a wall. But then why are electrons ejected in the direction of the electric vector?

Comment: The electrons are given extra energy with the result that they start moving faster.  That results in some of them actually moving towards the surface and having enough energy to escape.

Comment: But they are not moving in random directions. They are moving exactly in the direction of the electric vector of the photon. This has been observed in many experiments. If the electrons are being ejected by the photons the law of conservation of momentum is violated.

Comment: The electrons do not necessary get out at once.  There may be interactions with other electrons/ions before emission from the surface.

Comment: But then they would be ejected in random directions.

Comment: In the early 1920s many experiments showed that the direction of ejection of photo electrons was in a direction parallel to the electric vector. e.g. https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.23.137. These experiments are deeply significant. However, after the invention of quantum mechanics a few years later, no one seems to have regarded them as being of any significance.